# How to use two newline characters as delimiter when reading input using read

Tags: bash, read

The following command:

```bash
$ read input
hello \
> world
$ echo "$input"
```

allows me to enter multiline input by using the backslash character.

I'm now looking to change this to allow the multiline input without the backslash.
I've tried using the `-d` option as follows:

```bash
$ read -d '\n\n' input
```

however this doesn't work as expected.

```bash
> hello
world
```

every time I hit enter, it just keeps going.

The literal newline in bash is `\n`, so I would have expected the input to stop after two newlines were found.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Note this, in the `help read` output: "-d delim continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather than newline" -- the delimiter is only one character.

Comment: Additionally, to get bash to recognize the escape sequences, you need to use [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Comment: @glennjackman so you're saying I can't use `read` for this?

Comment: For multiline input, I'd use `input=$(cat)`

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, I don't think you can do that directly with `read`. So just do it manually:

```
#!/bin/bash
# the function writes to global variable 'input'  
getinput() {
    input=
    local line
    # read and append to 'input' until we get an empty line
    while IFS= read -r line; do 
        if [[ -z "$line" ]]; then break; fi
        input+="$line"$'\n'
    done
}
printf "Please enter input, end with an empty line:\n"
getinput 
printf "got %d characters:\n>>>\n%s<<<\n" "${#input}" "$input"
```

Strictly speaking, that doesn't look for two newlines, but just an empty input line. It could be the very first one.